# Azure cloud service auto scaling through classic portal

Tags: azure

We have a IaaS cloud service, trying to auto-scale. Weird is, we didn't see the scale happen, we configure the auto-scale based on CPU metric, range is 20-60, looking at logs of one of active server, its CPU is 40%, but seems there is no extra instance got booted up and added to the farm.

Looking at Microsoft documentation, it says 'based on the average percentage of CPU resources that it uses.', what does this average meant, daily average, hourly average or (ideally under our impression) the time duration (the scale up wait time) since the farm's last scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All instances are included when calculating the average percentage of CPU usage and the average is based on use over the previous hour.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/#automatically-scale-an-application-running-web-roles-worker-roles-or-virtual-machines